# React error when using ReferenceArrayInput in admin on rest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, admin-on-rest

I'm trying to use the ReferenceInputArray field in admin on rest

```
    <ReferenceArrayInput label="Clients" source="clients" reference="Client" allowEmpty>
     <SelectArrayInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceArrayInput>
```

but i get this error:

uncaught at handleFetch Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, description, __typename}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of Chip.

Comment: What version of `admin-on-rest` are you using ?

Comment: i'm using admin-on-rest v1.2.3

Comment: Have you installed `material-ui-chip-input` by yourself ou just use the one on which depends `admin-on-rest` ?

Comment: i tried both. i added the material-ui-chip-input v0.17.1 but nothing changed

Comment: Just found out that if i remove the allowEmpty option in the editComponent the error disappear but the field value is not showing up

Comment: This is weird, the `SelectArrayInput` does not care about `allowEmpty`